# Choose the correct option for the following determinant

Tags: determinant

[image]

Do we have to expand the determinant to find sum of Coefficients or coefficient of any power of $x$ or can it be calculated without expanding too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient $a_7$ is $\Delta(0)$, so
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & -3 \\
-3 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=21
$$

Similarly, for $\Delta(1)$ substitute $x=1$:
$$
\Delta(1)=\det\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 4 \\
4 & 3 & -2 \\
-2 & 5 & 2
\end{bmatrix}=132
$$

You also have $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7=\Delta(1)$, so
$$
a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6=\Delta(1)-a_7=111
$$

You can do $\Delta(-1)$ yourself (it gives $-32$).

Answer (score 0):

Forget about all but the constant terms for each element in order to simplify the calculation of $a_7$.

Similarly you can forget about all but the leading terms for each element in order to calculate $a_0$.
Once you have this, you can subtract it from $\Delta(1)$ to obtain $\sum_{k=0}^6 a_k$.